# Schema cache path for a database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, schema

Where does the rails stores the schema cache for a database ? I know that we can specify schema_cache_path in the database.yml file. But if we didn't specify the path, in which path rails actually stores the schema ?

Answer (score 0):

once you run `rake db:schema:cache:dump` you will be able to see the file under /db/schema_cache.yml